# How to run Bitcoin Core both main and testnet on the same machine?

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet

How to run Bitcoin Core both main and testnet on the same machine?
I want to be able to communicate with both block-chains via RPC.

Do I need to run 2 instances on bitcoind / bitcoin-qt.exe for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I need to run 2 instances on bitcoind / bitcoin-qt.exe for that?

Yes. If `bitcoin-qt` is already running and on `mainnet` then open up a command shell and type:

```
>bitcoin-qt -testnet
```

This will launch a second bitcoin-qt on testnet using the default `-datadir=` and `-conf=` options.

The `-testnet` option uses the folder `{default bitcoin datadir path}/testnet3/` and the default `bitcoin.conf` file by default. If you wish for your `testnet` instance to have different options to your `mainnet` instance then add the `-conf={file}` option after `-testnet` on the command line.

This works much the same for `bitcoind`.